# delay the IFrame

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I have a requirement to delay the Iframe by 1 or 2 secs till all other section of the visualforce page complete its load. But my code below is not working.

```
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var iframe = document.getElementById('loadIFrame'),src = iframe.src;
  iframe.src = '';
  document.onload =  function(){iframe.src = src;}
</script>

<iframe Id="loadIFrame" name="loadIFrame" src="https://login.salesforce.com" scrolling="true" height="600px" width="1600px">
</iframe>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Could anyone please help me in fixing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOM is loaded yet, so your code wouldn't work because the element won't be found. However, you should probably just be adding it dynamically:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            var iframe = document.createElement("iframe")
            iframe.src = "https://login.salesforce.com"
            iframe.scrolling = true
            iframe.name = iframe.id = "loadIFrame"
            iframe.width = 1600
            iframe.height = 600
            document.getElementById("content").appendChild(iframe)
        }, 2000) // wait 2 seconds after loading
    })
</script>

<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Hello SFDCFox, sorry for the delayed response. I tried the code you posted within pageblock. But for some reason its not rendering the URL. Do i have add anything to your code to render the URL.

Comment: @Dinesh Looks like X-Frame-Options prevents login.salesforce.com from being placed in a frame. Also, I noticed a missing ) in my code (updated). Regardless, you're probably going to need to use a different method to log in.